# Appending lines to a file whose path is defined in an environment variable

Tags: elixir, github-actions

I enjoy using Elixir as a scripting language in GitHub actions.

At the moment, defining output values for a workflow step in Github actions requires that you run the following bash command:

`echo "key=value" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT`

I guess what's happening here is that we are appending `key=value` to some file whose path is stored under the environment variable `$GITHUB_OUTPUT`.

I'm trying to do this from Elixir, but I'm a bit stuck. I've tried the following:

```
IO.puts("echo 'key=value' >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT")
IO.puts("key=value >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT")
System.cmd("echo", ["hello=world", ">>", "$GITHUB_OUTPUT")
```

How can I append lines to a file whose path is stored in an environment variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`System.fetch_env!/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/System.html#fetch_env!/1) to get the environment variable, and [`File.open!/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/File.html#open!/2) with [`IO.puts/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/IO.html#puts/2) to append to the file:

```elixir
"GITHUB_OUTPUT"
|> System.fetch_env!()
|> File.open!([:write, :append])
|> tap(&IO.puts(&1, "key=value"))
|> File.close()
```

Comment: That worked, both locally and in GitHub actions. Thank you.